# How to set visibility on a component in RTC source control

Tags: rtc

The visibility of a component within a stream is 'Project Scoped', this is the view I see when I double click the component from within the stream :

[image]

I would like it to be 'Team Private' as 'Project Scoped' means this component is visible just to the team ?

On the stream this component belongs to I have set the 'visibility' to a team area, does this mean that just members of the team will be able to view this component even though at the component level the visibility is 'Project Scoped' ?

When I attempt to 'change' the visibility of this component by clicking 'change' button (in above screenshot) this is the error I receive :

[image]

How can I change the visibility to 'Team Private' ?

Update : To change the visibility :

```
1. expanded the stream tree within 'Team Artifacts'
2. right click the component
3. click 'Change Owner'
4. Change to team that this component is to be private to and ensure 'Restrict to members of this team area and its child team areas'
```

Following these steps the visibility changed to 'Team Private'

However, changing the component visibility via opening the stream and updating same component from within the stream does not change the 'Visibility' . I think this is RTC inconsistency ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the access management possibilities are explained in "[Controlling access to source control in Rational Team Control](https://jazz.net/library/article/215)".

The "[Read protect some components but give public access to others](https://jazz.net/library/article/215#protect_some)" is close to what you are looking for.
But you can also [protect at the folder level for a specific team area](https://jazz.net/library/article/215#protect_some_files).

> Prior to RTC 40, there was no access control on the folder or file level in the repository so keep this in mind when laying out your file system with certain documents that should be hidden. Access control at the file and folder level was added in RTC 4.0.

Regarding the "scoped" notion:

> For components owned by the project area, its access is scoped the same way the project area is.

(so only the member of the project area can see/access it)

> For components owned by an individual user, the owner can specify how it is scoped.

That is why you get the:

```
You cannot change the access control on components owned by project area and team area.  
They inherit their access control settings from a project area or team area.
```

You need a component owned by a user in order to change its visibility.

Comment: @user470184 when you say that "it doesn't change the visibility", are you talking about the visibility of the stream or the component?

Comment: I'm talking abouot the component